# Bootstrap date picker display month name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap date picker and I want to display the month in the date picker field. See below 
image.

[image]

I tried following code:

```
$('#example1, #example2, #example3').datepicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
});
```

But it is no use. Any one can help me?

**Edit:** I want to display the month name (14 August 2014) in the text field instead of the date that are displayed now - 14/08/2014.

Comment: what exactly u want???

Comment: You have to show like this "14 August 2014" in the text field?

Comment: Yes. I want to show "14 August 2014" in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$('#input_date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd M yyyy'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you will get your desire output from the following code

```
$('#example1,#example2,#example3').datepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy",
});
```

but I would like to recommend you to use class rather using multiple IDs for multiple fields. For example suppose use class name example1 for all fields then the code will be something like this

```
$('.example1').datepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy",
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is responsible for formatting the date.

MM - 01 02 ... 11 12

MMM - Jan Feb ... Nov Dec

MMMM - January February ... November December

The following code format the month name in the text field

```
$('#example1, #example2, #example3').datepicker({
    format: "dd MMMM yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use dd/mm/yyyy (MM display month name, mm numeric)

format
String. Default: “mm/dd/yyyy”

The date format, combination of d, dd, D, DD, m, mm, M, MM, yy, yyyy.

d, dd: Numeric date, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 5, 05.
D, DD: Abbreviated and full weekday names, respectively. Eg, Mon, Monday.
m, mm: Numeric month, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 7, 07.
M, MM: Abbreviated and full month names, respectively. Eg, Jan, January
yy, yyyy: 2- and 4-digit years, respectively. Eg, 12, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I think  that the only way is to implement the `hide()` event and change the text field:

```
months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
           "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

 $('#datePickerID').datepicker()
         .on("hide", function(e) {
           var temp=e.delegateTarget.firstElementChild.value.split('/');
            var selectedMonthName = months[parseInt(temp[1])-1]; 
            e.delegateTarget.firstElementChild.value=temp[0]+' '+selectedMonthName+' '+temp[2];
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
     $('#example1').datetimepicker({format:'D-MMM-YYYY'});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

Try separate initialization

```
$('#example1').datepicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
});

$('#example2').datepicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
    });

$('#example3').datepicker({
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
    });
```

**OR**

Give all of them a single class "example" then use

```
$('.example').datepicker({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
        });
```

Check documentation
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#format;